# Getting json in google chart TABLE

Tags: php, json, google-visualization

I used the product Google chart a few times to get json data in a chart. I find it still difficult but I am good in code cut and paste
 ;-)

Now I want to create a table from a valid json file.

I don't get it work:-( What do I wrong/forget in the code bellow?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['table']});    
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawTable);

function drawTable() {
var jsonData = $.ajax({
url: "https://myRemoteWebsite.com/json_scripts/objectsActionsData.php?aid=239",
dataType: "json",
async: false
}).responseText;

       data.addColumn('string', 'name');
       data.addColumn('date', 'date');
       data.addColumn('string', 'description');
       data.addColumn('number', 'id');
       data.addColumn('string', 'comment');
       data.addColumn('number', 'amount');

var table = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsonData);
table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '100%'});
      }

</script>
```

Where the remote json file "objectsActionsData.php?aid=239" returns valid JSON data like:

```
{
"data": [{"name":"John Smith","date":"2017-12-12","description":"second production","amount":"174","id":"2372","comment":"Comes with two"},{"name":"Miss Blake","date":"2017-10-30","description":"Steef Jobs","amount":"259","id":"2324","comment":"Red Socks"},{"name":"Elvis white","date":"2017-07-09","description":"grey band","amount":"41","id":"1879","comment":"Moved to Iceland"},{"name":"Silly Parker","date":"2017-05-20","description":"While blanks","amount":"78","id":"1679","comment":"You have to call first"}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the data should be added to --> `google.visualization.DataTable`
NOT --> `google.visualization.Table`
the latter being the chart object, which takes a dom element...

also, don't use `async: false` on ajax, it's been deprecated

recommend following setup, you'll need to update the url
for example purposes, i've hard-coded the json data you provided in the `fail` callback,
which can be removed...

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['table']
}).then(function () {
  // create chart
  var container = $('#chart_div').get(0);
  var chart = new google.visualization.Table(container);
  var options = {showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '100%'};

  // create data table
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'name');
  data.addColumn('date', 'date');
  data.addColumn('string', 'description');
  data.addColumn('number', 'id');
  data.addColumn('string', 'comment');
  data.addColumn('number', 'amount');

  getData();
  function getData() {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'getdata',
      dataType: 'json'
    }).done(function (jsonData) {
      loadData(jsonData);
    }).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      var jsonData = {"data": [{"name":"John Smith","date":"2017-12-12","description":"second production","amount":"174","id":"2372","comment":"Comes with two"},{"name":"Miss Blake","date":"2017-10-30","description":"Steef Jobs","amount":"259","id":"2324","comment":"Red Socks"},{"name":"Elvis white","date":"2017-07-09","description":"grey band","amount":"41","id":"1879","comment":"Moved to Iceland"},{"name":"Silly Parker","date":"2017-05-20","description":"While blanks","amount":"78","id":"1679","comment":"You have to call first"}]};
      loadData(jsonData);
    });
  }

  function loadData(jsonData) {
    // load json data
    $.each(jsonData.data, function (index, row) {
      data.addRow([
        row.name,
        new Date(row.date),
        row.description,
        parseFloat(row.id),
        row.comment,
        parseFloat(row.amount)
      ]);
    });
    drawChart();
  }

  $(window).resize(drawChart);
  function drawChart() {
    // draw chart
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for solving my case!